# ado.net oracle stored procedure output varchar parameter split-cut-truncated

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have an Oracle-stored procedure (SP) which returns a `varchar` parameter, but when I execute the SP and try to read the output, the string is cut. When I execute the SP on Toad and made an `dbms.output`, the string is well returned.

```
procedure testStringOutput(num in number, str out varchar2)
as

V_C NUMBER(38);
V_E VARCHAR2(2000);
begin
    select '12345678910111213141516171819PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP'
    into str
    FROM DUAL;

exception
when others then
V_C := SQLCODE;
V_E:= SQLERRM;
dbms_output.put_line(V_C||'-> '||V_E);
end;
```

The way I call the SP as script:

```
declare
P2 VARCHAR2(2000) :='';
begin
PKGTEST.TESTSTRINGOUTPUT(1,P2);
dbms_output.put_line('output string - > '||P2);
end;
```

The output:

```
output string - > 12345678910111213141516171819PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
```

The way the SP is called from c#:

```
public void TestOutputString()
{
    string str = string.Empty;
    using (connection)
    {
        OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
        objCmd.Connection = connection;
        objCmd.CommandText = "PKGTEST.testStringOutput";
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("num", OracleType.Number).Value = 0;
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("str", OracleType.VarChar, 2000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        foreach (OracleParameter parameter in objCmd.Parameters)
            if (parameter.Value == null)
                parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            str = (objCmd.Parameters["str"].Value.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

But when I inspect the response string, it was split until `123456789101112131415161718`, the another part (`19PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP`) was lost. See this [image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1YEB-QCNgYc2-WbdSJlFTuflXCyA94fSFsxSBlWtMrS89Ikb6x6I-dtal7JOvUAo6yO5qNl_d2n4WYk6BsU-6PuH2xHMc_LS=w1896-h816).

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I'm sure it happened, SP's return messages to WCF service, but when the client received the response, it was split.

Comment: Are you sure? May be it's splitted in VS debugger window. Try printing it in a Console window.

Comment: yes im sure, it happenes with a big stored procedure called from a java client of wcf that's why i try with a smile test and the trouble continues.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have to use Oracle data provider odp.net instead of  ado.net - System.Data.OracleClient (deprecated) and it works.